# How to trigger jQuery hover() when cursor is on top of the target?

Tags: jquery, jquery-hover, mouseenter, mouseleave

jQuery `hover()` works correct, when the mouse moves from outside to inside the target, and the other way around. But when the mouse is exactly on top of the target `hover()` does not trigger anything.

Use case: Cursor is in middle of the window and the page loads an element in the middle, there is no mousing in our out of the element happening.

How can `mouseenter` be triggered when the mouse is over the target?

And some code (although this question is more conceptual):

```
function showControls() {
    $('#controls').show();
}

function hideControls() {
    $('#controls').hide();
}

$('.panel').hover(showControls, hideControls);
```

And the HTML:

```
<div class='panel'>
    <div id='controls'>
        <button>Del</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: @HamzaHaider I have tried hover(), mouseenter() and mouseleave() and tons of Googling.

Comment: can you please show your code

Comment: @HamzaHaider Yes, but it's not going to help much :)

Comment: what exactly do you want when mouse is over the target?

Comment: @Anki I want showControls() to be triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question :)

Adding the following fixes the problem:

```
$('.panel').onmousemove(showControls);
```